# JQgrid checkbox onclick update database

Tags: jqgrid

I have a checkbox column in my JqGrid which get loaded from DB, so it is either checked or not checked when it is loaded.

What i want is : If checkbox is being checked or uncheked by user i want to update DB in at same. I dont want  user to press enter or anything. only 1 click and send action to DB

name: 'Aktiv', index: 'Aktiv', width: 100, edittype: 'checkbox', align: 'center',formatter: "checkbox", editable: true, formatoptions: {disabled : false}

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can set a `click` event handler inside of `loadComplete`:

```
loadComplete: function () {
    var iCol = getColumnIndexByName ($(this), 'Aktiv'), rows = this.rows, i,
        c = rows.length;

    for (i = 1; i < c; i += 1) {
        $(rows[i].cells[iCol]).click(function (e) {
            var id = $(e.target).closest('tr')[0].id,
                isChecked = $(e.target).is(':checked');
            alert('clicked on the checkbox in the row with id=' + id +
                '\nNow the checkbox is ' +
                (isChecked? 'checked': 'not checked'));
        });
    }
}
```

where

```
var getColumnIndexByName = function(grid, columnName) {
    var cm = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'colModel'), i, l;
    for (i = 1, l = cm.length; i < l; i += 1) {
        if (cm[i].name === columnName) {
            return i; // return the index
        }
    }
    return -1;
};
```

Instead of the `alert` you should use [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to send information to the server about updating the checkbox state.

You can see a demo [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/LocalAdjacencyTree6.htm).

Comment: works perfectly, now i need to figure out how to send action futher to  my controller which will send it futher to DB. Oh i think ive got it now

Comment: @HardikMishra: You are welcome! Currently I prefer don't make *multipe* binding of `click` events. It's enough to use just *one* click on the whole body of grid. See [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14537512/315935) or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13765086/315935)

Comment: @Oleg How to make it so that it focuses only on the Checkbox?

Comment: @NewHistoricForm: Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean. In any way the answer is old. I find the solution from [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24239416/315935) better.

Comment: @Oleg I mean that only clicking the checkbox will show the alert message. In my case i want it to make clicking on checkbox column save entire row data for corresponding row.

Comment: @NewHistoricForm: Try [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/EditableCheckbox1.htm) which is simple modification of the demo from [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24239416/315935) which I referenced before. It should do what you need.

Comment: @Oleg Thank you this seems to work. ubt in you demo when I click outside the checkbox it still fires event. How to fix that?

Comment: @NewHistoricForm: It's what you asked in your previous comment: "i want it to make clicking on checkbox column save entire row data". I don't understand what exactly you want. In any way you can easy modify the code inside of `beforeSelectRow` of the demo to any results which you need.

Answer (score 1):

A small correction in the loadComplete: function().
in the demo you can find that even after the checkbox is checked, if you click outside the checkbox in that cell, the value gets changed to 'false' from 'true'.

To avoid this, just give the focus exactly on the checkbox alone by doing the following.

```
for (i = 1; i < c; i += 1) {
    $(('input[type="checkbox"]'),rows[i].cells[iCol]).click(function (e) {
        var id = $(e.target).closest('tr')[0].id,
            isChecked = $(e.target).is(':checked');
        alert('clicked on the checkbox in the row with id=' + id +
              '\nNow the checkbox is ' +
              (isChecked? 'checked': 'not checked'));
    });
}
```

and thanks for the answer :-) (@Oleg) helped me a lot..in time of course.. ;)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. The click event does not fire when using this code. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

To change values of other column based on click of checkbox

```
var weightedAvgPriceIndex = getColumnIndexByName($(this), 'WeightedAveragePrice'),
    rows = this.rows,
    i,
    c = rows.length;

for (i = 1; i < c; i += 1) {
    $(('input[type="checkbox"]'),rows[i].cells[iCol]).click(function (e) {
      var id = $(e.target).closest('tr')[0].id;
      isChecked = $(e.target).is(':checked');
      var x = $('#' + id + ' td:eq(' + weightedAvgPriceIndex + ')').text();
      $('#' + id + ' td:eq(' + weightedAvgPriceIndex + ')').text(Math.abs(x) + 10);
    });
}
```