# jqgrid update database on checkbox click

Tags: javascript, jqgrid, checkbox

Its a thread upon this one: [JQgrid checkbox onclick update database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208412/jqgrid-checkbox-onclick-update-database)

right now i got it to work, but now i am able to click on the column cell and update happends in my DB, but what i really want is that update happends only on checkbox click only, not cell click.

Comment: I tried out the demo, that was mentioned by Oleg in your menthioned link and I had to explicit click on the checkbox. If I clicked the cell, the checkbox would not have been activated. I used FF 3.6.20, Safari, IE 8 and Chrome 12.x

Comment: In the demo I first get `iCol` - the index of 'Aktiv' column with the checkboxes. Then I enumerated all rows of the grid and set `click` handle **only in the `iCol`** column of every row. So clicking of another cells not works. What behavior you want to have exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understand you correct and you want to set `click` handle on the checkbox only and not on the cell having the checkbox. In the case you should just change the line

```
$(rows[i].cells[iCol]).click(function (e) {
```

to

```
$("input", rows[i].cells[iCol]).click(function (e) {
```

See the modified demo [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/LocalAdjacencyTree7.htm).

Comment: gah... i missed "," and it didnt worked ofcourse :D my stupid small mistackes... thanks again Oleg