# jqGrid has missing id in checkbox

Tags: jqgrid

new to jqGrid.  I'm displaying a grid, readonly so far, but now with a checkbox in one column.  However, the checkbox is not produced with id or name attributes - which according to the documentation it will be. Any pre-requisites to get the id's?  Ideally I'd like an id on teh checkbox that is like the prefix + rowid.

Code is:

```
 jQuery("#grdProducts").jqGrid(
        {
            url: '<%: Url.Action( "GetPageByCode", "Products" ) %>',
            datatype: "xml",
            mtype: 'POST',
            colNames: [ 'Code', 'Language', 'Type', 'Name', 'Price £', 'Web', 'Dimensions', 'Actions' ],
            colModel:
                [
                    { name: 'code',     index: 'ProductCode',   width: 120, key: true },
                    { name: 'language', index: 'Category1',     width: 100 },
                    { name: 'type',     index: 'Category2',     width: 140 },
                    { name: 'name',     index: 'Name',          width: 240 },
                    { name: 'price',    index: 'PriceGross',    width: 60, align: "right" },

                    { name: 'web',                              width: 32, align: "center",    
                                  editable:true, edittype:'checkbox', editoptions: {value:"True:False" }, 
                                  formatter: "checkbox", formatoptions: {disabled : false } },
                    { name: 'dimensions',                       width: 120, sortable:false },
                    { name: 'actions',                          width: 120, sortable:false }

               ],

            height:660,

            rowList:[ 20,50,100 ],
            pager: '#pgrProducts',
            sortname: 'ProductCode',

            // speed improvement - as long as certain features not needed
            gridview: true,

            // shows the 'showing 1 - n of total' in the pager, ... and the text to display
            viewrecords: true,
            recordtext: "showing products {0} - {1} of {2}",

            // alternate colour rows
            altRows:true, altclass: 'gridAltRow',

            // shows sort arrows in titles
            viewsortcols: [ true ],

            // the grid outer caption
            caption: 'Products by product code',

            // configurable page size
            rowNum:  <%: Model.PageSize %>,

            // double click on a row goes to the edit row page
            ondblClickRow: function( rowid )
            { 
                document.location.href = '/Product/Edit/' + rowid;
            } 

        }
      );

    } );
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you need to have `id` attribute in the checkbox? If you need to get checkbox it will be very easy in your case because there are only one checkbox in the row, so you can use

```
$('#' + rowid + ' input:checkbox')
```

If you need to detect 'click' event for example to the checkbox you can find the corresponding code in the demo from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7210627/315935).

Comment: It looks like we won't be able to use jqGrid: Our JSF framework generates IDs for every form element.  If these IDs change, our application breaks.  What a huge disapointment...

Comment: @jahroy: You should describe the problem more detailed in new question, but the fact that you *change id* shows that you chosen not good design in your application. Typically the ids can be *generated for new elements only*, but one never change the id value of *existing* elements.

Comment: Please see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12701876/778118  I believe it describes what _MAY_ be a bug that I discovered in jqGrid.

Comment: Just to clarify, we are using a third party JSF component library that creates html elements with auto-generated ID and name attributes.  jqGrid is removing the _name_ and _onClick_ attributes from our _checkboxes_ when they appear in the first column of a table row.  I belive this may be a bug.  When I said _if these IDs change_, I was referring to the fact that they were being changed by jqGrid, which was causing  problems.

Comment: @jahroy: I can repeat the suggestion to post new question with more details. One place *data* in the grid during typical usage of jqGrid. There are some alternatives to place HTML fragments inside of jqGrid, but the best way depend on the context.

Comment: Please see the link I just posted in my comment.  It is a new question with more details.  Here it is again: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12701876/778118

Comment: @jahroy: I wrote the answer on your question.