# JQGRID - maintain check box selection state - page refresh / redirect / reload

Tags: javascript, asp.net, checkbox, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

**H**ow to maintain the checkbox selection after the page refresh / reload / redirected from some other page in **JQGRID**.

I am working in `aspx` pages.

I am *able* to maintain the checkbox selection state in paging using following code:

```
    gridComplete: function () {
     var currentPage = $(this).getGridParam('page').toString(); //retrieve any previously stored rows for this page and re-select them
     var retrieveSelectedRows = $(this).data(currentPage);
     if (retrieveSelectedRows) {
        $.each(retrieveSelectedRows, function (index, value) {
        $('#list').setSelection(value, false);
     });
    }
   },
   onPaging: function (a) {
     var pagerId = this.p.pager.substr(1); // ger paper id like "pager" 
     var pageValue = $('input.ui-pg-input', "#pg_" +           $.jgrid.jqID(pagerId)).val();
     var saveSelectedRows = $(this).getGridParam('selarrrow'); //Store any selected rows 
     $(this).data(pageValue.toString(), saveSelectedRows);
  }
```

But, *how* to maintain the checkbox selection state in ***page refresh / redirect / reload*** in `JQGrid` ?

Also, I tried the following code on `Window.OnLoad`, but it is not working

```
$("#list").trigger("reloadGrid", [{page: 1, current: true}]);
```

Comment: Is there any _solution / Ideas / Suggestions_ for this _requirement / problem_ ?

Comment: You didn't commented the answer which I published for you. Do you have an interest in the solution?

Answer (score 2):

The implementation of selection over multiple pages of the grid is very tricky in old versions of jqGrid. I posted [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8172723/315935), [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8547852/315935) (try [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ColumnChooserAndLocalStorage2_.htm)) with the corresponding implementations.

On the other side the scenario of selection of multiple rows over multiple pages is very common. Thus I implemented new feature in free jqGrid. Now one can just use new `multiPageSelection: true` option in combination with `multiselect: true`. It changes the behavior of selection in the following way:

- one can use `selarrrow` array to *pre-select* some rows directly during creating the grid.
- the array `selarrrow` can hold the ids of rows from *other* pages. The array `selarrrow` will be not cleared on changing the page. jqGrid just select rows if it's rowid is in the array `selarrrow`.
- click on "Select All" checkbox in the header of checkbox columns fills `selarrrow` with *all* rowids of local `data` (from all pages)

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/multiPageSelection.htm) demonstrates the new feature.