# jqGrid getLocalRow returning false when data property is set

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

Am having issues using `getLocalRow` along with data property

```
var $grid;
getGrid = function () {
    $grid = $("list");
    $grid.jqGrid({
        mtype: "POST",
        colNames: [],
        colModel: [
            ....
        ],
        pager: "",
        loadonce: true,
        multiselect: true,
        gridComplete: function () {
           var data = $(this).getDataIDs();
           for(var i=0; i < data.length;i++){
                $(this).setSelection(data[i]); // select all rows by default
           }
        },
        loadComplete: function (data) {

        },
        loadError: function (xhr) {

        }
    });
    return $grid;
};
```

There are two ways am populating the grid based on 2 scenarios.
In scenario 1, am just hitting server url and returning the data as JSON and populating in the grid. Using this option, when I iterate thru the selected rows and perform getLocalRow am getting the required o/p.

And in scenario 2, I construct a data object and pass it to the same grid. The problem occurs here when I iterate and use getLocalRow in this context am getting false for all the selected rows instead of the row data but works fine with getRowData.

scenario 1 :

```
$grid.jqGrid("clearGridData");
$grid.jqGrid("setGridParam", {url: '..', datatype: "json"}).trigger("reloadGrid");
```

scenario 2 :

```
$grid.jqGrid("clearGridData");
$grid("setGridParam", { data: MyOWNobject}).trigger("reloadGrid");
```

Accessing getLocalRow :

```
var sel=[];
for (i = 0; i < $grid.jqGrid("getGridParam").selarrrow.length; i++) {
    sel.push($grid.jqGrid("getLocalRow", $grid.jqGrid("getGridParam").selarrrow[i]));
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but you code have no test `data` and no `colModel` and it's unclear where (at what moment) you use `getLocalRow`. Could you prepare **the demo** which can be used to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @Oleg,please check this http://jsfiddle.net/y9KHY/90/ . Click Test to load the data and when you hit Test2  button, **getLocalRow for the selected row is returned as false** whereas if I use **getRowData** it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the filling of the grid. Every row of the grid have to get unique `id`. If your data already have some column with unique data then one can use `key: true` in the column to inform jqGrid to use the value from the column as the rowid.

I tested last time free jqGrid always with the data, which contains either `id` property in every column of have `key: true` property for a column which values one want use as the rowid. If you would follow the rule then the problem which you reports will not exist. See the demo http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/y9KHY/92/ which uses the code

```js
$("#submit1").click(function () {
    var $grid = $("#gGrid");
    var grps = [
            { Name : "A",  Group : "11" },
            { Name : "B" , Group : "1122" }
        ];
    $grid.jqGrid({
        data: grps,
        colModel: [
            { name: 'Name', key: true },
            { name: 'Group' }
        ],
        cmTemplate: {width: 200},
        rownumbers: true,
        multiselect: true,
        gridComplete: function () {
            $("#cb_" + this.id).click();
        }
    });
});

$("#submit2").click(function () {
    var $grid = $("#gGrid"), p = $grid.jqGrid("getGridParam"), i;

    for (i = 0; i < p.selarrrow.length; i++) {
        alert("Data  > " + JSON.stringify($grid.jqGrid("getLocalRow", p.selarrrow[i])));
    }
});
```

The demo http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/y9KHY/93/ uses `id` property in input data.

Nevertheless, the usage of not full input data, without specifying rowid is allowed in general. Thus the described above behavior of free jqGrid is a bug. The bugs is fixed already in the code of free jqGrid on GitHub. You can verify it in the demo http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/y9KHY/94/, which uses the code directly from GitHub. I plan publish the next version soon.

Comment: @Oleg: Is this published yet. I am using free-jqgrid 4.13.6. When I debug, I see the ID of each rows are 'jqg41', 'jqg42' etc... And sometimes it is 'jqg61', 'jqg62' etc...

Comment: @SKumar: The rowids will be like `'jqg41` if you **fill** the grid in the wrong way (if the source data of the grid don't contain any id information). Nevertheless the data `p.selarrrow[i]` will be the rowids generated by jqGrid in the case and the code from my answer will work correctly.