# How to select all the rows in all the pages of jqgrid?

Tags: c#, asp.net, select, checkbox, jqgrid

I am able to `select all` the rows in a page by clicking on `selectall` checkbox.
But I am unable to select all the rows across all the pages. Is it possible?

Comment: Do those rows even exist in the DOM at the time?  If not then no, you can't select something that isn't there.  What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: My requirement is to have a `select all rows` checkbox or button. After clicking this, I need to select all the rows in all the pages at a time. Then, in the same page, another button is present for displaying those selected rows details in the another page. Only thing, I need is to select all the records in all the pages(paging)..Thanks.

Comment: So you just need a button which, when clicked, takes the user to a page where every record is displayed.  Seems like the part about selecting the records isn't entirely necessary.

Comment: But when paging, it should behave accordingly..If selected all clicked, the page viewed should be selected all the records..

Comment: I can't believe your username was available at all.  Let alone just eight months ago.

Answer (score 0):

The answer on your question depend on many aspects of the implementation. You should specify which `datatype` you use (for example `datatype: "local"`), which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7).

I develop free jqGrid fork and I have implemented `multiPageSelection: true`  option, described in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33021115/315935). See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/multiPageSelection.htm). The new option allows to set the ids of the rows, which need be selected in `selarrrow` option of jqGrid. It allows "pre-select" the rows. Moreover it changes the behavior of "Select All" checkbox too.