# jqgrid searchToolbar datepicker not filtering

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I am now using jqGrid(version: jqGrid 4.14.1-pre, free jqGrid), and would like to have a search toolbar with a datepicker. 
When I click the textbox, the datepicker successfully pops up and it updates the textbox with the date I choose. However, it does not filter the data.

What I really wanted was sopt:["le"] but failed. For checking purpose, I tried the "eq" too. But in both cases, all the data rows disappear.

I did set the

```
loadonce:true
```

and tried

```
$('#list')[0].triggerToolbar();
```

Since I did use older version of jqGrid, I updated the latest version in GitHub and tried but still failed.

```
{label: 'LockedDate',   name: 'LockedDate',     index: 'LockedDate',    sorttype: 'date',   clearSearch: true,
        sortable: true,
        resizable: false,
        hidden: false,
        search: true,
        formatter: 'date', 
        formatoptions: {srcformat: 'm/d/Y h:i:s A', newformat: 'm/d/Y h:i:s A'},
        searchrules: {date: true},
        searchoptions: {
             sopt: ["le"],
            dataInit: function (element) {
                            $(element).datepicker({
                                    dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
                                    changeYear: true,
                                    changeMonth: true,
                                    showButtonPanel: true,
                                    onSelect: function () {
                                        $(this).keydown();
                                        $('#list')[0].triggerToolbar();
                                                },
                                    onChange: function () { 
                                             $('#list')[0].triggerToolbar(); }
                                            })
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
```

As I remeber rightly, I saw Oleg's answers on stackoverflow (sorry, lost the link) talking about the datetime parsing problem in older version. Is my date format the cause?

Since other search toolbar works well, I don't think this is the problem of pager or grid itself. Could anyone please help me where I set the datepicker wrong??

Thank you! :)

I'm not sure whether this jqGrid code is needed, but just in case I will put:

```
$('#list').jqGrid({
    url: '/LockedObjects/GetLockedObjects',
    datatype: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset-utf-8",
    mtype: 'GET',

    colModel: [
        {label: 'LockedBy', name: 'LockedBy',index: 'LockedBy', sorttype: 'text',   clearSearch: true,},
        {
            label: 'LockedDate', name: 'LockedDate', index: 'LockedDate', sorttype:'date', clearSearch: true,
                sortable: true,
                resizable: false,
                hidden: false,
                search: true,
                formatter: 'date', 
                formatoptions: {srcformat: 'm/d/Y h:i:s A', newformat: 'm/d/Y h:i:s A'},
                searchrules: {date: true},
                searchoptions: {sopt: ["le"],
                                dataInit: function (element) {
                                        $(element).datepicker({
                                            dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
                                            changeYear: true,
                                            changeMonth: true,
                                            showButtonPanel: true,
                                            onSelect: function () {
                                                $(this).keydown();
                                                $('#list')[0].triggerToolbar();
                                                },
                                            onChange: function () { $('#tbLockedPartiesHistory')[0].triggerToolbar(); }
                                            })
                                        }
                                }
                }],
    rowNum: 20,
    rowList: [20, 30, 50],
    sortName: 'LockedDate',
    ignoreCase: true,
    viewrecords: true,
    sortOrder: 'asc',
    loadonce: true,
    multiselect: true,
    jsonReader: {
        repeatitems: false,
        root: 'rows',
        page: 'page',
        total: 'total'
    },
    height: 'auto',
    pager: '#listPager',
    loadError: function (xhr, status, error) {
        console.log(xhr);
        console.log(status);
        console.log(error);
    }
});

$('#list').jqGrid('filterToolbar', {searchOnEnter: false, ignoreCase: true, searchOperators:true,defaultSearch: 'cn' });
$('#list').jqGrid('navGrid', '#listPager', {edit: false,
                                            add: false,
                                            del: false,
                                            refresh: true
                                            });
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following `searchoptions` should work:

```
searchoptions: {
    sopt: ["le"], // or any other search operation
    dataInit: function (element) {
        var self = this; // save the reference to the grid
        $(element).datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
            changeYear: true,
            changeMonth: true,
            showButtonPanel: true,
            onSelect: function () {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    self.triggerToolbar();
                }, 0);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I'd recommend you to make some additional changes in your code to simplify it or to fix some options:

- there are no `contentType` option in jqGrid. To set `contentType` parameter of underlying `jQuery.ajax` function one should use `ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: "application/json; charset-utf-8" }`
- it's better to remove the options `mtype: 'GET'`, `ignoreCase: true`, `height: 'auto'`, which have **default value** for free jqGrid.
- the option `sortOrder: 'asc'` should be removed. There are exist no `sortOrder` option (only `sortorder` option with the default value `'asc'`). In the same way the option `sortName: 'LockedDate'` is wrong and it will be ignored. The correct option will be `sortname: 'LockedDate'`.
- you should replace `jsonReader: {repeatitems: false, root: 'rows', page: 'page', total: 'total' }` to `jsonReader: { repeatitems: false }`. All other properties of `root, page, total` of `jsonReader` have **default value** and thus there can be skipped. In the most cases even `jsonReader: { repeatitems: false }` can be skipped because free jqGrid try to detect `repeatitems`.
- it's recommended to use `pager: true` instead of `pager: '#listPager'`. You can remove unneeded `<div id="listPager"></div>` from the HTML page. Free jqGrid will create the corresponding div *automatically*. You can *skip* the pager option in the methods `navGrid`, `inlineNav` and so on. The call of `navGrid` could be like `$('#list').jqGrid('navGrid', {edit: false,..});` in the case.
- you can specify the *default* searching options like `searchOnEnter: false, ignoreCase: true, searchOperators:true, defaultSearch: 'cn'` inside of `searching` parameter of jqGrid. It simplifies the later usage of `filterToolbar` or searching dialog. For example, you can use jqGrid option `searching: { searchOperators: true, defaultSearch: 'cn', closeOnEscape: true, searchOnEnter: true, multipleSearch: true, multipleGroup: true}`.
- It's recommended to **remove** `loadError` callback. Free jqGrid has **default** callback, wich will display errors on loading jqGrid data from the server. The errors will be displayed in the div between the column headers and the grid body (see [the picture](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html#grid-internal-div)). By specifying the `loadError` callback will will display less information as free jqGrid displays the default.
- you should cleanup `colModel` items. The definition of the column `LockedBy`: `{label: 'LockedBy', name: 'LockedBy',index: 'LockedBy', sorttype: 'text', clearSearch: true,}` should be replaced to `{ name: 'LockedBy', searchoptions: { clearSearch: true } }`. The properties `label, index, sortable, hidden, search` of the column `LockedDate` should be removed and the property `clearSearch: true` should be moved inside of `searchoptions`.

You can consider to use `multiPageSelection: true` and `forceClientSorting: true` options of free jqGrid additionally.

The option `forceClientSorting: true` force *local* sorting and filtering of the data returned from the server *before* the first page will be displayed. If you use `sortname: 'LockedDate'`, then *the server have to* sort the returned data by `LockedDate`. If you use the option `forceClientSorting: true`, then the server can return unsorted data and free jqGrid sort the data *localy* before displaying the first page.

The option `multiPageSelection: true` is described in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33021115/315935). [The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/multiPageSelection.htm) demonstrates the results. The option allows 1) hold the selection over the pages (one can select rows on one page, change the page, select rows on another page, go back to the first page and the previously selected rows will be hold) 2) one can *pre-select* rows.

Comment: Hello, @Oleg ! Thank you for quick and so detailed answer. I did not know that there were so many errors like it. Since I could not figure out why my one did not work, I did put a lot of default settings, but it seems like those just made the grid performance worse. And for the result of the changes, my grid now works!! Thank you again for helping me to find the errors. Have a good day :)