# how to change checkbox id in jqGrid in case of multiselect : true

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

JqGrid takes dynamic checkbox ids in case of

```
multiselect: true
```

I want to change id for checkbox because i want to automate click of every checkbox.
Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: The only goal of `id` is to be unique. One need just know it, but I don't understand why you want to change it. The id will be used by jqGrid internally and changing of the id can break existing functionality. Please describe more detailed what you need to implement and why. It's important to know which version of jqGrid you use (can use) and from which fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS]() or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7). Free jqGrid allows to *generate* grid with selected rows (see [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/multiPageSelection.htm))

Comment: See [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33021115/315935) for details. Additionally one can use `setSelection` and `resetSelection` methods to select or unselect the rows *inclusive* checking or unchecking of the multiselect checkboxes. By the way, one can use `multiselectPosition: "none"` option to create free jqGrid with multiselect functionality without the multiselect checkboxes.

Comment: I have already mention in description that i want to automate click of every checkbox. I know that the goal of id is to be unique. but i want to set that unique id by my custom logic.